# How to allow multiple carts per customer?

Tags: php, shopware

I want to allow a customer to have multiple carts.
Based on a `custom field` of a product i want to add a product to `cart 1` or `cart 2` of that customer. The customer should later see a dropdown in the off canvas cart.

I was searching for a matching event, but i could not find one. My idea was to listen to the `BeforeLineItemAddedEvent`, then load the product based on the `referenceId`.

But i think this event is not right as i am not able to replace the `cart`.
How can i solve my problem? thanks!

```php
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeLineItemAddedEvent::class => 'doMagic'
        ];
    }

    public function doMagic(BeforeLineItemAddedEvent $event)
    {
        $productId = $event->getLineItem()->getReferencedId();
        # load product id here
        # check custom field "cart-type"
        # either put to default cart OR create a new cart
        # and add then the line item
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the long run? Do you want the customer to create two different orders? Or is it more like a wishlist? This might need a lot of change to the system. You could as well filter out the products in the checkout or in the cart display based on the product's attribute?

Comment: i want to have several orders as i have some products that require a specific payment method because the products are only "pre-orders". So i want to create a second cart for products which are marked as "pre-order" products.

Comment: Did you think about dividing the orders somehow when going to the checkout page? i.e. first checkout the normal products and remove them from the cart, then guide the user to the checkout for the pre-orders. Most comfortable for the user would of course be to select two payment methods in the checkout and create two orders in the background. I guess the addresses are always the same?